# Practices for Focus, Concentration, Memory?

Tags: mantras, yoga, smriti, mind, yantra

Any Mantra, Yantra, Yoga for Focus, Concentration, Memory...

Which concept should I look into, If I want to know more about, Focus, Concentration and Memory in Hinduism

Comment: You do not need Hinduism for this. You can use meditation or sit in a quiet room.

Comment: practice tratak or focus on sri yantra